# Is it safe to install php on windows server?

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, wordpress, iis-7.5

I am a beginner on windows platform.
I have a dedicated server on windows server 2008 and IIS 7.5.
I want to install Wordpress on it and with other php scripts.

Is it safe to use php with other asp.net files? and how to install php without effecting the working website?

Comment: you might want to look into http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: You can run it with your existing IIS 7.5 server. http://www.howtogeek.com/50432/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php alongside with asp in the same server. In the past, I even used an application that some files where written in php and some in asp. There is no conflict in that.

To install php on windows server, either follow [the official guide of php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) or try this [interesting tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/50432/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/).

As for the mySql, I had to [download it](http://www.mysql.com/) and install it manually, but it works perfectly without conflicting with MSSQL. I didn't use phpmyadmin, as the build-in database manager of mysql was good enough for me. But phpmyadmin is just a php application, so it will run perfectly since php will be installed. You can find [more details on its official website](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

Comment: Thank you. Just one more information. Will it make me able to use phpmyadmin and mysql database?

Comment: I updated the answer to include indformation on mysql and phpmyadmin as well.

Answer (score 1):

Installing PHP shouldn't affect your asp or existing websites.

You can follow the manual guide on the php website but this is much easier: http://php.iis.net/
It will do the manual configuration for you.